# polymonial of $n+1$ degree inequality

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Let:
$$p(x) = x^{n+1} + a_{n}x_{n} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0 $$

Show $\lVert p \rVert_{\infty}^{[-1,1]} \geq \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}$

Obviously my first naive approach is induction.

First step ($n=0$, if you'd rather prefer you can start with $n=1$): $$max(x + a_{0}) \geq 1$$ $$ 1 + a_{0} \geq 1 $$ $$  a_{0} \geq 0 $$

From this point I'm not sure - $a_i$ coefs are not given (even an absolute value). Is it good approach anyway?

Cheers! Thanks for your time and any help!

Comment: The polynomials with minimal $\infty$-norms are Chebyshev polynomials. Check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Minimal_.E2.88.9E-norm

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks.